# Generate functions in python from source tables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have excel file with many sheets, on every is that type of table for some category, name of category is sheet name. Tables have same structure, different is only nr of rows and values off course.

```
cluster left    right   keyval
1   0   3   kg
2   3   8   
3   8   15  
4   15  50
```

In python, I need make automaticaly that function from table:

```
def convert_range(row: pd.Series) -> str:
    if row["kg"] <= 3:
        return "0-3"
    elif 3 < row["kg"] <= 8:
        return "4-8"
    elif 8 < row["kg"] <= 15:
        return "9-15"
    elif 15 < row["kg"] <= 50:
        return "16 plus"
```

I hope I have described my problem clearly. I absolutely don't know how to do that...

Comment: hint: you need to write generic code that will be **using** data from your sheets to drive it's logic. That should be clean task if files are structured the same. Definitely do not go into generating code.

Comment: Yes, file structure is the same